# nodejs - mongodb - how to find all where a != b?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

this is how I imagine it

```
    //b is variable
    collection.findAll({a:'!'+b}function(err, cursor) {

    });
```

What the correct way to that query, find all result where a != b ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here

[nodejs - mongodb - how to find all where a != b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287719/nodejs-mongodb-how-to-find-all-where-a-b/6289279#6289279)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the not equals '$ne' for comparation

```
collection.findAll({a: {'$ne':b }}, function(err, cursor) {});
```

Check out this [advanced queries manual page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries) for more detailed explanations.

Comment: I tested the code, it will fetch everything that equals a. :(

Comment: Try the same query in your mongodb console window like this: db.nameOfCollection.find({a: {'$ne':b}}). It should return the documents from the collection where a != b. If it does, the problem is elsewhere and not in the code snippet from your question

Comment: also try using collection.find() instead of findAll()